# I need to export console output to 2 different files in Java. In first file I'm able to get data and the second file is empty

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, selenium, automation

I need details of 10 persons and inside every person there are different number of details. I need all that that but the data is in 13 rows. so i need to all these 13 rows and print data like a paragraph. I need to export this data to files so i can use them for different purposes.

```
 driver.findElement(By.id("searchActivitySubmitButton")).click();

    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    PrintStream prevConsole = System.out;
    PrintStream myconsole = new PrintStream(new File("C:\\FileName15.txt"));  // exporting data in first file
    
    System.setOut(myconsole);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(@id,'requestAchFileUploadDetails')])[" + i + "]")).click();  // checks the data of the first 10 people whom data i need
        
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='See transactions']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3700);

        List<WebElement> listRows = driver.findElements(
                By.xpath("//table[@id='transactionActivityTable']//tr[contains(@id,'transaction_')]")); // for every row there are multiple columns which all data need to extracted. 

        for (int j = 1; j <= listRows.size(); j++) {

            driver.findElement(By.xpath(
                    "(//tr[contains(@id,'transaction_')]//i[contains(@id,'icon-activitySeeDetails')])[" + j + "]"))
                    .click();

            
            for (int k = 1; k <= 13; k++) {

                String keys = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//dt[contains(@id,'transactionDetailDataSet')]/span/span)[" + k + "]")).getText(); // inside every person there are 13 rows. 

                String value = driver
                        .findElement(By.xpath("//dl[@class='dataset row stack center']//dd[" + k + "]")).getText();
                map.put(keys + " ; ", value);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }

            for (Map.Entry<String, String> m : map.entrySet()) {

                System.out.println(m.getKey() + "  " + m.getValue());

            }
            
            System.out.println("\n");
        }

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.navigate().back();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.navigate().back();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        
    }
    System.setOut(prevConsole);
    myconsole.close();
    PrintStream mycons = new PrintStream(new File("C:\\chase\\sftp\\ach_transactions_summary\\Duplicate.txt")); // trying exporting data in second file
    System.setOut(mycons);
```

// Data is exporting only in first file and second file is empty.

Comment: Don't use `System.out.println` and `System.setOut` if you want to write to a file. Instead just directly do `myConsole.println()`. `System.setOut` is a very specialized API that should not be used for general purpose stuff like that.

Comment: Nothing got written into the file because that code doesn't write anything into the second file. Setting `System.out` doesn't mean that everything that was written there before somehow will also appear in the other file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing outputted to the second file since you send nothing to `System.out` after defining `System.setOut` to the second file by `System.setOut(mycons);`

Comment: Can you explain a bit more, so i can use it. Thanks

Comment: See Joachim's note below the question itself